# Execute bash script with params from Javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, linux, bash

I have some Javascript code that is used to determine a param that has to be then forwarded to a bash script on the target device. The bash script then copies a new file across and does a reboot of the system. I am using AJAX to do the call to the bash script and the code is as follows:

```
var config = get_config(); // Simply returns an integer

var xml_http = get_xml_http_object();
xml_http.open("GET", bash_script_id + "?" + config, false);
xml_http.send(null);
```

The bash script looks as follows

```
#!/bin/sh
CONFIG_NUMBER="$1"

cp /config_file$CONFIG_NUMBER /file_to_use

reboot
```

The script is correct and works if I use it from the command line directly on the machine and manually pass in a variable however when called from
Javascript the system does the reboot but does not copy the file. I have omitted some debug code and exception code for instance checking that `$1` is not empty but this does not seem to be the issue. Any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue. The bash script has to be updated to use $QUERY_STRING and not $1. This can then be parsed(if you pass more than one param) to get all the params needed

```
#!/bin/sh
CONFIG_NUMBER=$QUERY_STRING

cp /config_file$CONFIG_NUMBER /file_to_use

reboot
```

**Note**

To work with command line as well as from Javascript you would have to accommodate both $QUERY_STRING and $1 etc.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try adding a "sync" between the copy and reboot in case the filesystem isn't flushing correctly...

Comment: Hmm, would this not be the case at all times however, even running it on the command line, which doesn't have the same issue? I assumed that the file could be the same independent of the call site assuming privileges as correct which they are..

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `reboot` command and use this command instead of your line:

```
cp /config_file$CONFIG_NUMBER /file_to_use 2> error_copy.log
```

This will attempt to copy the file and if there are any errors it will output them to error_copy.log..

I am suspecting that the file/directory write privileges might not be configured correctly on your system. In other words the question is that if the user which copies the file has the right to do so..

Comment: This would be a possible solution but the system has to do a reboot in order for the new settings to be used sadly

Comment: No prob.. just check it so we can determine the problem ;) I just wanted to save some time by not restarting.. this isn't a solutionjust a way to determine the problem

Comment: No that wasn't the issue. I have solved it and added an answer with the solution :) Thanks anyway